# Joomla module that displays articles' thumbnail and small description on rows and columns?

Tags: joomla

I'm having trouble finding a joomla module that displays articles on rows and columns, each article with a thumbnail and a title or a small description. For e.g. I want to put it on my first page with 3 columns and and 5 rows, for a travel agency website.

Does anyone know of such module? Could anyone help me find it?

If not, any idea of how I could build it? (very last resort)

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since native Joomla articles do not support thumbnails out of the box you are probably better off using a CCK to accomplish what you want. I know at least Zoo and K2 support images related to an item without any extra code and both have the ability to display content as you have described.

Comment: LOL no problem. BTW - if that is all you really need to do, I would go with K2 since it does it all right out of the box and works very similar to Joomla Articles. Zoo is more flexible and can do more, but it's also a lot harder to figure out.

Comment: Seems that it really was HARD to figure out, and K2 didn't work out either. I ended up using virtuemart with a custom module, displaying everything the way I want by editing the fly page.